# PWA availability and possibilities

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, progressive-web-apps

In reality, I got a few questions:

1. Can a PWA work without an website? I mean, my app "potato" not needing an "potato.site"
2. If so, is it possible to make http requisitions? I mean, check if a directory has the assets the app needs and if not, download from the server
3. It is possible to save data localy with or without the questions above?
4. Is it possible to the user login with an google account inside the PWA?

This is my very first time building an app and I stumbled into PWA because I though it would be good to reuse those skills.

I want something that runs smoothly and its not heavy, because it will be a menu-like game, so I dont want the mobile melting/big for nothing.

Tried searching many times about those questions above, but found some people/websites saying "can/cannot" with very vague answers.

What I understanded about PWAs:

- They are websites stored in a installable
- Its possible to download it from your active website to your desktop/mobile to act as a local app
- Its possible to make it work offline
- It uses the browser resources to show the app without the browser UI (I loved that)

But I feel I'm missing something, that I didnt understood. But I want to read your thoughs about it, recommendations and tips if possible to help me make a decision (or I'll be using React Native).

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: if point 1 is true, then what server does point 2 use?

Comment: PWA depend on installing from a website. Only native mobile apps (Obj-C/Swift or Java/Kotlin) can be installed via the respective platform app store. Be very specific about features you need as PWA running in background (not foreground visible app) is mixed/not working due to increased platform security (both Android & iOS).